# Difference Between Single And Double Vertical Bar (|, ||) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For a while, I have used "||" as the "or" indicator. One day, I was debugging some things in a console, and I accidentally put a single | instead of two. It still worked as expected.

```js
console.log(0||1); // 1
console.log(0|1); // 1
```

Is there any difference? Here, there evidently isn't, but there might be some hidden difference that I don't know about. I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I assure you I have looked for the answer beforehand.

Comment: Getting the same result for only one test case, is not an evidence or indication that they are equal. `0/1` and `0*1` also have the same result, but `*` and `/` are for sure not the same. So you should always test with more than just one combination. `2|1` is `3`  and `2||1` is `2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called a [bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR), meaning it ORs the individual bits that compose a value based on binary rules.

```
a   b   a OR b
0   0     0
0   1     1
1   0     1
1   1     1
```

For your example, `0` in binary is just `0000`, and `1` in binary is `0001`.

Thus `0|1` is:

```
0000 | 0001
```

Which, when we apply the table above between each binary digit of the two numbers:

```
0 or 0 = 0
0 or 0 = 0
0 or 0 = 0
0 or 1 = 1
```

give us `0001`, which when converted to decimal becomes `1`.

---

The way `||` ([logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)) behaves is using coercion rules which returns the first truthy item (or just the last item) in a sequence of `||`.

Since `0` is falsy, `0 || 1`, will return `1`.

---

Just because the answers happen to be the same in these two situations, does not mean that the operations always produce equal results.

For instance:

```
2|3 === 3
2||3 === 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a [bitwise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR) OR.

> Performs the OR operation on each pair of bits. a OR b yields 1 if either a or b is 1

`||` is a [logical](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) OR.

In your example, `0|1` will evaluate to `1`, because `... 0000 | ... 0001` evaluates to `... 0001`.

`0||1` will evaluate to `1` because `0` is falsy so it'll return the right operand `1`